# AWS: Command works in command line, but not PHP's exec

Tags: php, permissions, exec, mysql

I'm trying to allow a simple PHP form to create a backup of a database.  Based off my research thus far the best approach is using PHP's exec function.  When I run my PHP script, it is running under user `apache` and the exec function's second and third parameters return and empty array and `1`, respectively.

When I log in to my AWS EC2 instance and copy/paste the command as it was passed to the exec function it executes just fine!  The only difference I can tell is that I'm logged in as user `ec2-user` instead of apache.  I started messing around with the `/etc/sudoers` file, but all that did was break my svn-post-commit-hook-update-project script (which I'd created by following [this tutorial](http://brennydoogles.wordpress.com/2011/10/21/using-subversion-to-automatically-publish-your-website/)).

For reference, here are the two database-copy attempts I've made, using PHP and the exec function:

```
// method 1
$command = "/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/mysqldump -u ".getDBUsername()." $password ".getDBDatabase()." | mysql -u ".getDBUsername()." $password $new_db";
$output = array();
$return = null;
$output = exec($command, $output, $return);
var_dump($output);
```

The second try I hav emade is piping the mysqldump to a .sql file then reading it back in, but the .sql file never gets populated (though it will be created).

```
// method 2
$dump_command = "sudo mysqldump -u ".getDBUsername()." $password".getDBDatabase()." > ./temp.sql";
$output = null;
$return_var = null;
exec($dump_command, $output, $return_var);
var_dump($output);
exec("sudo mysql $new_db -u ".getDBUsername()." -p".getDBPassword()." < ./temp.sql");
```

**Notes:**

1. `$password` does contain the `-p` tag if the password is set (and yes, without a space between it and the password).
2. I have attempted giving the directory where the file is created (or the .php script which contains either of these exec commands) to apache with the `chown` command, but it hasn't made a difference.

Any suggestions on what to try?  I suspect simply giving user `apache` the permissions that `ec2-user` has would suffice, but haven't figured out how to do that, and again, my edits to `/etc/sudoers` has only broken things thus far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing AWS CLI command from php results in Unable to locate credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21946360/608639), [AWS CLI command works on Bash, but not with PHP shell_exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50927931/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this answer elsewhere and worked for me:

> First off you shouldn't need to sudo to run mysqldump. I assume that's
>   the thing that's not working here - it's prompting for a password and
>   failing. Remove that and this should work fine if everything else is
>   set properly.