# Executing AWS CLI command from php results in Unable to locate credentials

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to run aws s3 cp command from within php code using shell exec. Following is the php code.

```
echo shell_exec("sudo aws s3 cp s3://<bucket>/somefolder/somefile s3://<bucket>/someotherfolder/somefile --region ap-southeast-1 --acl public-read");
```

The file is not getting copied and The output from echo is the following

"Unable to locate credentials Completed 1 part(s) with ... file(s) remaining"

**Note1: I have already set the credentials using aws configure command**

**Note2: If I run the exact same command directly from terminal, it works fine.**

Any idea?

Comment: Related: This type of operation can be accomplished with the AWS SDK for PHP. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-s3.html#syncing-data-with-amazon-s3

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

```
<?php

    putenv('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=your-region');
    putenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=YOURACCESSKEYID');
    putenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=YOURSECRETACCESSKEY');

    $output = shell_exec('aws s3 cp ./file.txt s3://MYBUCKETID/ 2>&1');
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";

?>
```

Comment: Please consider explaining your answer and why it worked

Comment: worked for me too. I guess putenv adds a session of environment variable during the php execution so the 'shell_exec` doesn't have any trouble finding the env variables

Answer (score 2):

The AWS CLI sets credentials at ~/.aws/config, and the aws php sdk looks for them at ~/.aws/credentials.

So:

```
cd ~/.aws
mv config credentials
```

Solved what I think is the same problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

From your terminal, you can then run:

```
$ cat ~/.aws/config
[profile eb-cli]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXXXXX

$ aws configure
```

and then you will be asked for 4 values:

> 1. Access Key ID (Access Key) - This is the shorter of the two values.
> 2. Secret Access Key
> 3. Default region name (type in 'us-east-1')
> 4. Output format (type in 'json')

then

```
$ aws s3 sync s3://<bucketname>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a permission/location issue of the configuration file.

Credentials set using AWS CLI, is written in a special file in the *current user's* path. PHP I guess is executing in other permissions (not as the same user). I would suggest you should keep the configs in a separate files and pass to the CLI [this way](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#config-file-location). You also need to ensure that the specific environment variable is available inside PHP shell_exec.

Answer (score 0):

To extend off of user1464317:

I found this problem exists with Yosemite vs Mavericks. The AWS CLI for Mavericks looks for permissions in "~/.aws/config", where Yosemite looks in "~/.aws/credentials".

If using cron, you can set the environment variable in crontab -e like so:

```
# Mavericks
AWS_CONFIG_FILE="/Users/YOUR_USER/.aws/config"

# Yosemite
AWS_CONFIG_FILE="/Users/YOUR_USER/.aws/credentials"
```

Or you do as user1464317 implied, move the file over:

```
mv config credentials
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve the issue, Follow the following steps:

1. copy .aws directory from /home/non-rootUser/.aws to /var/www
2. Now change the directory to /var/www (cd /var/www)
3. Change the permissions:
   /www$ sudo chmod -R 755 .aws
4. Change Ownership
   /www$ sudo chown -R $USER:$USER .aws
5. Recheck

Comment: Please delete your answer. Putting the AWS credentials in the web server directory is a HUGE security risk. Plus your answer does not solve the question.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue.
And I finally fixed it by this.

```
putenv('AWS_CONFIG_FILE=your-credential-file');
exec(...)
```

It seems the php user can't locate the correct credential file.
And it could be fixed by setting the environment variable.