# Executing AWS CLI command from php cannot locate credentials

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have the exact same issue as [Executing AWS CLI command from php results in Unable to locate credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21946360/executing-aws-cli-command-from-php-results-in-unable-to-locate-credentials)

I did:

```
cd ~/.aws
mv config credentials
```

But it didn't help.

So what I did is, both config and credentials have the same content:

[default]

aws_access_key_id = AKIAJIPLT472C32RD6AQ

aws_secret_access_key = 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

output = json

region = ap-southeast-1

The code I'm using in my PHP file is:

```
$s3 = system("aws s3 cp /var/www/html/v2/upload/__rmx4hqf.png s3://<bucket>/somefolder 2>&1");
```

Comment: remove `2>&1` from the end to get the error.

Comment: @Jigar when i remove this line error is not showing, but file is still not being uploaded

Comment: you should get the error in `$s3` so `var_dump($s3)`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `php` command cannot locate aws credential file because the user you ran `$ aws configure` is different from php's effective user. You didn't supply enough information about how you ran configure command or how php script is executed, so it's just my guess.

What happens if you explicitly pass credential file's path via environment variable `AWS_CONFIG_FILE` (e.g. `$s3 = system("AWS_CONFIG_FILE=/path/to/credential aws s3 cp ...`)?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your region

```
$s3 = system("aws s3 cp /var/www/html/v2/upload/__rmx4hqf.png s3://<bucket>/somefolder 2>&1 --region ap-southeast-1");
```

Answer (score 0):

like [quiver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2239016/quiver) say apache2 run from diffrent user then termina user
you can see apache user  ENV vars with the command `getenv();`
to add vars to apache2 ENV you need to use putenv("string");

you need to add aws cerdentials in this way

`putenv('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=' . $region);`
`putenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=' . $key);`
`putenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=' . $secret);e`
`print_r(getenv());`

only this solution wotks for me when i try to run aws cli from php file

[original answer aws forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=692394)