# AWS CLI not adding files to S3 when called from my website

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a Amazon Linux ec2 installation that is running Apache.  When a user signups up for my website, I dynamically generate a download package.  After the package is created, I want it to be uploaded to my Amazon S3 bucket for download.  I am using the following command:

```
/usr/bin/aws s3 cp /path/to/local/file.zip s3://my/bucket/dir/
```

The command above works when I execute it from the command line.  It also works when I run it from a bash file locally.  However, when my website runs the bash file after a user signs up, it does not work.  Apache owns the bash file, so I do not think it is a permissions issue.  Apache also owns the folders and files.  When troubleshooting, I was able to run the "aws s3 help" command and saw the output in the browser.  However when I ran "aws s3 ls" I did not get output.

The webserver on the Amazon Linux ec2 instance is only for handling files and downloads.  It is not my main website.  My main websites sends requests to my ec2 instance to create/upload the files.  So users do not interact with the site.

Comment: You need to pass the AWS environment variables to the web server.  The web page runs as the user of the web server.

Comment: ok so how would I do that?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/setup-aws-cli.html and https://stackoverflow.com/q/21946360/2182349

Comment: I have the aws cli set up and everything.  i can even upload/download files using the CLI when I type the commands in.  The problem is that when the command is run by the "apache" user, it does not work

Comment: The StackOverflow link has several answers

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.